# How do I change Chrome's formatted indent spacing from 4 spaces to 2 spaces?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The feature: Chrome > Dev Tools > Sources > {page}:formatted

default tab indent is 4 spaces, can I change it two 2? How do I configurate it?

Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dev Tools, press <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter Settings, Preferences section,
set to `2` under "Sources" at "Default indentation":

---

[image]